# Calculating return from a factor model

Tags: regression, time-series, pca, interpretation, risk

I've been trying to figure this one for weeks so your advise is very appreciated. 
I have log returns for the past 5 yrs on the following indexes: NYSE, Communication, Growth and Large Cap. I performed PCA on those and kept 2 ‘unobservable factors’ with loadings as follows:

```
NYSE Index  0.2599870   0.6090115
Communications  0.7952713   -0.5660120
Growth          0.3918862   0.2710737
Large Cap   0.3825905   0.4850304
```

Orthogonal regression of NYSE returns on 2 factor scores gives me 2 betas equal to factor loadings (0.609 and 0.2599). Therefore betas for NYSE are:

```
            NYSE       Index Communications Growth  Large Cap
NYSE Index  0.316      0.337                0.309    0.359
```

respectively

To calculate delta R on NYSE in terms of the factors:

```
Return on NYSE= 0.316* R NYSE + 0.337* R Comm+0.309* R Growth +0.359 R Large Cap.
```

However this doesn’t actually work… What am I missing? How can I calculate Return on NYSE Index using PCA's common factors?

Comment: 1) What is `R` or `delta R`? 2) What do you mean under `common factors` when speaking of PCA?

Comment: Sorry if i didnt make it clear, R is return. What is the return of NYSE Index in terms of returns of 4 indexes? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will answer your question, but there is a blog post that explains technicalities of a statistical factor model: http://www.portfolioprobe.com/2012/11/12/the-guts-of-a-statistical-factor-model/

Comment: Oops, Sorry I wasnt clear. By return I dont mean PCA factor return.  I have those. I mean the return on NYSE index (returns data was used as variables in PCA originally) It's a factor model on equity index, where the factors are not specific like "p/e ratio" but rather statistical/unknown/pc1 and pc2.